# C# Open XML HTML to DOCX Spacing

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-word, export, export-to-word

I've been working on my site, and trying to create an Export to Word.  The export works well, converting HTML string to DOCX.

I'm trying to figure out how I can adjust the Line Spacing.  By Default Word is adding 8pt Spacing After and setting the Line Spacing to double.  I would prefer 0 and Single.

Here is the Function I created to Save a Word Document:

```
private static void SaveDOCX(string fileName, string BodyText, bool isLandScape, double rMargin, double lMargin, double bMargin, double tMargin)
{
    string htmlSectionID = "Sect1";
    //Creating a word document using the the Open XML SDK 2.0
    WordprocessingDocument document = WordprocessingDocument.Create(fileName, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document);

    //create a paragraph
    MainDocumentPart mainDocumenPart = document.AddMainDocumentPart();
    mainDocumenPart.Document = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Document();
    Body documentBody = new Body();
    mainDocumenPart.Document.Append(documentBody);


    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("<html><head></head><body>" + BodyText + "</body></html>"));

    // Create alternative format import part.
    AlternativeFormatImportPart formatImportPart = mainDocumenPart.AddAlternativeFormatImportPart(AlternativeFormatImportPartType.Html, htmlSectionID);

    //ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    // Feed HTML data into format import part (chunk).
    formatImportPart.FeedData(ms);
    AltChunk altChunk = new AltChunk();
    altChunk.Id = htmlSectionID;

    mainDocumenPart.Document.Body.Append(altChunk);

    /*
     inch equiv = 1440 (1 inch margin)
     */
    double width = 8.5 * 1440;
    double height = 11 * 1440;

    SectionProperties sectionProps = new SectionProperties();
    PageSize pageSize;
    if (isLandScape)
    {
        pageSize = new PageSize() { Width = (UInt32Value)height, Height = (UInt32Value)width, Orient = PageOrientationValues.Landscape };
    }
    else
    {
        pageSize = new PageSize() { Width = (UInt32Value)width, Height = (UInt32Value)height, Orient = PageOrientationValues.Portrait };
    }

    rMargin = rMargin * 1440;
    lMargin = lMargin * 1440;
    bMargin = bMargin * 1440;
    tMargin = tMargin * 1440;

    PageMargin pageMargin = new PageMargin() { Top = (Int32)tMargin, Right = (UInt32Value)rMargin, Bottom = (Int32)bMargin, Left = (UInt32Value)lMargin, Header = (UInt32Value)360U, Footer = (UInt32Value)360U, Gutter = (UInt32Value)0U };

    sectionProps.Append(pageSize);
    sectionProps.Append(pageMargin);
    mainDocumenPart.Document.Body.Append(sectionProps);

    //Saving/Disposing of the created word Document
    document.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();
    document.Dispose();
}
```

In searching, I found this code:

```
SpacingBetweenLines spacing = new SpacingBetweenLines() { Line = "240", LineRule = LineSpacingRuleValues.Auto, Before = "0", After = "0" };
```

I've placed it many places in my function, but I can't seem to find the correct place to Append this setting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I worked on the function trying to set the spacing in code, but wasn't able to remove the spacing.  I decided to try creating a Template Word Document and setting the spacing in that document.

I copy the template.docx file, creating the one I will use, then use the adjusted function below to add the HTML string:

```
private static void SaveDOCX(string fileName, string BodyText, bool isLandScape, double rMargin, double lMargin, double bMargin, double tMargin)
{
    WordprocessingDocument document = WordprocessingDocument.Open(fileName, true);
    MainDocumentPart mainDocumenPart = document.MainDocumentPart;

    //Place the HTML String into a MemoryStream Object
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("<html><head></head><body>" + BodyText + "</body></html>"));

    //Assign an HTML Section for the String Text
    string htmlSectionID = "Sect1";

    // Create alternative format import part.
    AlternativeFormatImportPart formatImportPart = mainDocumenPart.AddAlternativeFormatImportPart(AlternativeFormatImportPartType.Html, htmlSectionID);

    // Feed HTML data into format import part (chunk).
    formatImportPart.FeedData(ms);
    AltChunk altChunk = new AltChunk();
    altChunk.Id = htmlSectionID;

    //Clear out the Document Body and Insert just the HTML string.  (This prevents an empty First Line)
    mainDocumenPart.Document.Body.RemoveAllChildren();
    mainDocumenPart.Document.Body.Append(altChunk);

    /*
     Set the Page Orientation and Margins Based on Page Size
     inch equiv = 1440 (1 inch margin)
     */
    double width = 8.5 * 1440;
    double height = 11 * 1440;

    SectionProperties sectionProps = new SectionProperties();
    PageSize pageSize;
    if (isLandScape)
        pageSize = new PageSize() { Width = (UInt32Value)height, Height = (UInt32Value)width, Orient = PageOrientationValues.Landscape };
    else
        pageSize = new PageSize() { Width = (UInt32Value)width, Height = (UInt32Value)height, Orient = PageOrientationValues.Portrait };

    rMargin = rMargin * 1440;
    lMargin = lMargin * 1440;
    bMargin = bMargin * 1440;
    tMargin = tMargin * 1440;

    PageMargin pageMargin = new PageMargin() { Top = (Int32)tMargin, Right = (UInt32Value)rMargin, Bottom = (Int32)bMargin, Left = (UInt32Value)lMargin, Header = (UInt32Value)360U, Footer = (UInt32Value)360U, Gutter = (UInt32Value)0U };

    sectionProps.Append(pageSize);
    sectionProps.Append(pageMargin);
    mainDocumenPart.Document.Body.Append(sectionProps);

    //Saving/Disposing of the created word Document
    document.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();
    document.Dispose();
}
```

By using the template file, the line spacing is correct.

For those that might find this function useful, here is the code that calls the function:

```
string filePath = "~/Content/Exports/Temp/";

string WordTemplateFile = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/Content/Templates/WordTemplate.docx");
string DestinationPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(filePath);
string NewFileName = DOCXFileName + ".docx";

string destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(DestinationPath, NewFileName);

System.IO.File.Copy(WordTemplateFile, destFile, true);

SaveDOCX(destFile, HTMLString, isLandScape, rMargin, lMargin, bMargin, tMargin);
```

Comment: How can i insert html string to the header?

Comment: @AshitaShah, If the header is static, I would just make it part of the Word Template file. Might be able to use a bookmark:
`IDictionary<String, BookmarkStart> bookmarkMap = new Dictionary<String, BookmarkStart>();
                foreach (BookmarkStart bookmarkStart in mainDocPart.RootElement.Descendants<BookmarkStart>())
                    bookmarkMap[bookmarkStart.Name] = bookmarkStart;
                foreach (BookmarkStart bookmarkStart in bookmarkMap.Values)
                    if (bookmarkStart.Name == BookMarkName)
                        bookmarkStart.Parent.Append(altChunk);`

Comment: Thank you @MrMatt. The header and footer are not static.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the formatting because your code is only inserting HTML into a Word doc. To change the formatting, the HTML text needs to be converted to regular text and added to the Word doc as such. I was in a similar issue and using the HtmlToOpenXml library makes this quick and simple.

```
using HtmlToOpenXml;
```

Then the function:

```
    protected virtual void createWord()
    {
        string html = "*myHtml*";

        // Create WordProcessingDocument
        WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Create(ms, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document);
        MainDocumentPart mainPart = doc.MainDocumentPart;
        if (mainPart == null)
            mainPart = doc.AddMainDocumentPart();

        Document document = doc.MainDocumentPart.Document;
        if (document == null)
            document = mainPart.Document = new Document();

        Body body = mainPart.Document.Body;
        if (body == null)
            body = mainPart.Document.Body = new Body(new SectionProperties(new PageMargin() { Top = 1440, Right = 1440U, Bottom = 1440, Left = 1440U, Header = 720U, Footer = 720U, Gutter = 0U }));

        // Convert Html to OpenXml
        HtmlConverter converter = new HtmlConverter(mainPart);
        converter.ParseHtml(html);

        // Reformat paragraphs
        ParagraphProperties pProps = new ParagraphProperties(new SpacingBetweenLines() { Line = "240", LineRule = LineSpacingRuleValues.Auto, Before = "0", After = "0" });
        var paragraphs = doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Descendants<Paragraph>().ToList();
        foreach (Paragraph p in paragraphs)
        {
            if (p != null)
                p.PrependChild(pProps.CloneNode(true));
        }

        // Close the document handle
        doc.Close();
    }
```